# Symmetric matrix-Spectral theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

Assume we have a matrix $A$ let's say $100 \times 4$. We determine the product $B=A^{T}A$ Then by the spectral theorem

\begin{equation}
B =U^{T} \lambda U
\end{equation}

$B$ is a symmetric matrix $4 \times 4$. Is it impossible that is not invertible?

I was thinking that we cannot guarantee that is always invertible because maybe one of the eigenvalues is zero. But I am not sure if this is correct. In case one of the eigenvalues is zero then we need to calculate the pseudo-inverse?

Any help or comment will be helpful.

Comment: It's not true that $B$ is $4\times 4$ and why so many negations in "Is it impossible that it isn't invertible"? The matrices $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ share the same non-null eigenvalues (they also share multiplicities of these eigenvalues).

Comment: If you want $B$ to be $4 \times 4$ then I think you mean $B = AA^T$.  Do you want conditions on $A$?  I could choose $A$ to be the zero matrix, then $B$ is the zero matrix which is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. My question is if we have a square matrix then we can guarantee that none of the eigenvalues will be zero?

Comment: I don't want conditions on $A$. I was wondering if the matrix $B$ is always invertible

Comment: @user161260 As Jim showed, no.

Comment: take $A$ to be the zero matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that $B$ is non-invertible. Suppose every entry of $A$ was the same value, then every entry of $B$ is the same value, and so it is not invertible.

More generally, if $A$ does not have full column rank (4), then $B$ will not be full rank, and thus not be invertible.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but if we can guarantee that every entry of $A$ is not the same then B is always invertible? That's why I asked regarding the eigenvalues if we can guarantee that none of them will be zero. Because I know that every entry of $A$ is not the same.

Comment: That was an example where rank $A$ was 1. In general, if rank $A$ is less than the number of columns, then $B$ will be singular.